# Flash message with link_to in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a flash message and I want to add a link_to tag to it so the user can have a link within the flash message. My problem is that I am getting the error undefined method `link_to'.

sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email].downcase)

  if user.activated?
    //Log User In
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Account not activated. Check your email for the activation link.  #{link_to('Resend Activation Email', user.send_activation_email)}"
   redirect_to root_url
  end

  flash[:warning] = "Account not activated. Check your email for the activation link. #{link_to('Resend Activation Email', user.send_activation_email)}"
end
```

Is it possible to add a link_to within a controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to('Resend Activation Email', user.send_activation_email)
```